# Create solid torus with geometric algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have created an algorithm for tracking a vessel's centerline in 3 dimensions, and traveling through that centerline. My supervisor asked me whether I could add a small theoretical section on creating a torus, (that means a solid torus tracking along the outer boundaries of the vessel) but whether this could be done with GA.

1)I would therefore like to ask for suggestions on how to do this. I have read some GA, but I can't easily visualize operations with multivectors,since they involve different dimension objects. I'm not sure how to go about creating a torus just by using the outer product, or multivector operations.

2) If we forget about GA, what would be a good idea of creating a solid torus in normal geometrical coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand centerline. The path the center of the object traces? In that case, supposing this path is given by some vector-valued function ${\bf r}(t)$, you're looking to put a small "tube" around ${\bf r}(t)$?

Comment: Imagine we suddenly become tiny and start traveling inside a vessel. My algorithm has found this line, which we can follow and be at the center of this "tube", but the vessel is not a tube, because it might have curvature in space (a lot of it too), its size might change, etc. What I would like to do is tracking along r(t) as you said, to create this torus around the vessel walls, not the centerline itself. This means I have to compute the distance from the vessel walls (that is something I will easily solve) and then just create it.

Comment: What is a "vessel" here?

Comment: Blood vessels, located in the brain area.

Comment: Good question, @ChristianBlatter - I thought we were talking about ships at sea; that's the kind of "vessel" that sprang to my mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we are given a space curve
$$\gamma:\quad s\mapsto{\bf x}(s)\qquad(0\leq s\leq L)$$
parametrized by arc length, and assume that its curvature $\kappa(s):=|\ddot{\bf x}(s)|$ is nonzero for all $s$. The three vectors
$$\dot{\bf x}(s),\quad {\bf n}(s):={\ddot{\bf x}(s)\over\kappa(s)},\quad {\bf b}(s):=\dot{\bf x}(s)\times {\bf n}(s)$$
then form an orthonormal frame  moving along $\gamma$ , the so-called *Frenet frame*. Using this frame we can construct a  tubular surface $T$ with "soul" $\gamma$ and tubular radius $r>0$ as follows:
$$T:\quad (s,\phi)\mapsto {\bf x}(s)+r\cos\phi\>{\bf n}(s)+r\sin\phi\>{\bf b}(s)\qquad\bigl(0\leq s\leq L, \ \phi\in{\mathbb R}/(2\pi)\bigr)\ .$$
For fixed $s$ and variable $\phi$ we obtain a circle of radius $r$ with center ${\bf x}(s)$, and lying in the normal plane to $\gamma$ at ${\bf x}(s)$.

If $r$ is too large the surface $T$ will have selfintersections.